# Is Windows Form Application (in visual studio c++) automatically C++/CLI?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

I want to do a Windows Form Application in C++ but by making a simple hello world program (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9sGms_j3l2M) I got a common error (I guess it's common since it has been questiones here many times)

"Intellisense: Unavailable for C++/CLI"

So my question is, can I do a Windows Form Application in pure C++ (I really want IntelliSense and for other reasons too)

Comment: IntelliSense for C++/CLI is missing in VS2010 but is back again in VS2012.  However, Winforms support was dropped in VS2012.  You'll need VS2008.

Comment: if I get it right WPF is a newer way how to do Appliction in C++/CLI. Is there a WPF support in VS 2010 ? (I'd like to use a newer technology)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will be, and no you cannot do a Windows form application in pure C++. You would need another GUI framework for that, MFC or similar.

Question is: You usually use C++/CLI when you are calling some native C++ code etc, what is your use case?

If it's a project from scratch, can you not just use the C# for Windows forms.

Comment: so is it possible to make forms in C# and then _somehow_ use WinAPI  and other stuff here? (I need to use some really low level features).

Comment: You can import functions: [DllImport("User32.dll")]. But when you say really low level features, you may find you need native C++. If performance is not critical guess you could use the above method.

Comment: I am doing something very similar in functionality to Dropbox - so I will need to do something like minimalization to tray, etc. Syncing the dirs (this will be possibly done by a daemon) but still I don't understand ti very well so I don't know what I will need. Do you think this all can be solved with imported functions?

Comment: You can do most of that in C# id imagine, by low level I thought you meant memory management, hardware interaction etc. Google, what you want to do followed by the keyword C# and see if its possible.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Forms, by definition is a .NET technology, meaning that yes, it would be `C++/CLI`.

You can't write a Windows Forms application without using the .NET assemblies - you *may* be able to use interop to call to the .NET libraries, but this would be the long and difficult way about it.